# iPhone 6 is giving a clientWidth that's very different than its screen width and causing my media queries not to work right

Tags: css, responsive-design

https://codepen.io/glen_v/pen/ELaRPW

If I view this using the iPhone 6/7/8 setting in Chrome DevTools, it displays exactly how I want it to (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gx2S.png). Notice that clientWidth and screen.width are the same.

But if I view it on my actual iPhone 6, the page renders larger than the viewport and I have to swipe left to see the rest (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPEfF.png).

Notice that even though the screen width is only 375, the clientWidth is at 569. I have a media query set to change certain styles below 400, and I believe this inflated clientWidth is keeping that media query from firing.

I've already included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the header.

Any idea why this is happening?

(I only own this one physical phone, so I haven't been able to test on any others).

Comment: Does the codepen looks good on the phone?

Comment: I just realized that if I look at it on the phone in CodePen's debug view it displays exactly how I want. It's only when I'm in CodePen's regular full screen mode that I have the problem. So it must be some combination of CodePen, flexbox, and iPhone (or maybe all mobile, haven't tried on anything else). Whenever I take away any of those three elements it works. But when all three are in play, that's when I have the issue.